# Is the House of Odon considered historical or mythological?

Tags: royalty, anglo-saxons, genealogy, norse-mythology

I have just been on wikipedia looking through King Charles III's ancestry from father to father and it brought me to [Elimar I, Count of Oldenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elimar_I,_Count_of_Oldenburg) whom had a wife that claimed he was descended from [Widukind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widukind). Wikipedia claims quite matter of factly that Widukind was from the House of Odon, though offers no link to the House of Odon, and there appears to be no other information about the House of Odon on wikipedia.

I was always lead to believe that the House of Odon was mythological. So is the House of Odon considered historical or mythological?

Comment: I found playing with pay geneology tools that my family on my mother's side traces back to that as well, if you go far enough back. I guess its useful as a way to warn you that the further back you go, the more likely what you're getting back is garbage.  Still, I'd prefer to just not get the garbage.

Comment: I presume that your Odon is Woden or Odin.  I mention Odin in my answer to:  https://www.quora.com/How-far-back-can-you-trace-the-current-British-royal-familys-ancestry

Comment: @MAGolding. I would presume it is the same house. Though in this instance wikipedia has spelled it as Odon

Comment: Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaut & https://www.ourfamtree.org/browse.php?fid=3499 Widukind heritage/even "Immedingian genealogy not established", 'Egilmar first firmly attested'. The Gaut/'Hadu-goto' heroic ancestor is at the same time (Post/de-anglo?) Saxon myth and even that highly contested.